# expo keeps stopping android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am running an expo app on windows 10 using the android emulator.  The tunnel builds, and the simulator starts.  but expo keeps crashing on the simulator.

[image]

I tried uninstalling expo off the simulator, and rebooting the machine.  Any ideas?

Comment: How about Logcat? You can attach it to a debugger (like android studio) or use any logging app if you have root access

Comment: You can reproduce your app on expo.io. if it is also crashed there, please share your project through the snack.

Comment: Have you found a solution.I have the exact same problem.

Comment: It works for me on the iOS simulator.  So I was using iOS, still haven't had time to go back to play around with the android simulator.

Comment: Hello Amir! Did you mange to solve this issue?

Comment: No I never got the expo to stop crashing on my windows machine.  I haven't opened the project in a while however, so not sure how it would look if I tried again

Answer (score 12):

When use wrong style like you see image in styled component you used color in `squat('')` so, check your style then run your project

[image]

Comment: This helps a lot when I wrongly assign `'100%;'` instead of `'100%'`, i.e.: `<Image {...} style={{ maxWidth: '100%;' }} />`

Answer (score 0):

Try using another device in emulator with different sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured when doing style wrong like Vishal said. But it can also occur when messing up imports. Changing:

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

To:

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

Solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

This issue is often caused by errors while styling the components. Please check for typos.

This happened to me when I was first starting with React Native when trying to use rem units while the app was expecting a number, not a string.

Good luck!